# spring-data-monogdb query by Date via @Query annotation returns no result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to query mongodb using `@Query`. Actually, the date is truncated hours/minutes/seconds/millis to zero (both during insert and find query). I am trying to find records for specific day in year (e.g. 2019-10-10)

I see in mongodb fields of type date and stores as `2019-10-10T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

When I debug code reaching the spring's AbstractMongoQuery, I see following output:
`Query: { "someField" : "bla-bla", "date" : { "$date" : 1570665600000}}, Fields: {}, Sort: {}`
and no records returned back. This is to String output of Document, but I am not sure how it's actually sent to Mongo.

When I am trying to query monogdb manually with `{date: ISODate('2019-10-10T00:00:00.000+00:00')}` I do get results.

Using spring-boot 2.2.0.Release

See my code below:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObj, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'someField': ?0,'date': ?1}")
    List<MyObj> findWithDate(String someField, Date date);

    .........
    .........
    .........
    .........
}

@Document(collection = "test")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public class MyObj {
    @Id private ObjectId id;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    @Indexed private java.util.Date date;
    @Indexed private String someField;
}
```

Note: initially i didn't use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` and since date always came without hours/minutes/... in mongo it looked the same as I mentioned in description of problem.

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: `"date" :{$date: ISODate('2019-10-10T00:00:00.000+00:00')}` - Really should not get any results because it would not be valid syntax.` {"date" ISODate('2019-10-10T00:00:00.000+00:00') }` would be perfectly valid, but I would generally not expect it to match anything unless all your dates were actually stored with zero hours, milliseconds etc. In reality most people don't store timestamps that way and actually store according to **actual time**, which means it has millisecond value appropriate to the time of day and is thus within a "range" and **NOT** a singular value.

Comment: So the **more likely real problem** here ( despite the phrasing of the question ) is that the ***real*** values actually fall within a "range" instead of an exact value, and hence that should be your query. Otherwise if you really believe you tried something in the shell that works, then your application is simply pointing at the wrong place.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thx, I copied invalid expression to post - fix it. Here the working expression: ``{date: ISODate('2019-10-10T00:00:00.000+00:00')}``. I don't want to search for the range, but by equals, since I restrict dates to be (yyyy-MM-dd) in app when inserting and when searching the collection - normalize date to this format

Comment: Seems, java.util.Date class is not wrapped with ISODate